# Как победить ложную ошибку на метод InitializeComponent() проекта WPF в MS Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

При разных манипуляциях с файлами в проекте, например, удаление, перемещение и др. в **MS Visual Studio** всех версий на сегодняшний день, редактор иногда выдаёт **ложные ошибки** в коде `.cs` для `.xaml` ругаясь на метод `InitializeComponent()`, мол такой метод не существует. Но! Проект продолжает запускаться и работать без ошибок. Как это победить?
Если вопрос дубликат, ткните, не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю сам для всех, ну и для себя, вдруг забуду)
Этот косяк MS Visual Studio тянется уже не помню с каких версий. В моём случае, методом тыка, заметил, что при переключении конфигурации с Debug на Release, проблемы в редакторе исчезают, но при возвращении на Debug - снова проблемы.

**Решение проблемы:**

Создать новую конфигурацию с любым названием через диспетчер конфигураций. Убедиться, что конфигурация Debug в редакторе стала адекватной. После этого удалить только что созданную конфигурацию также через диспетчер конфигураций.

Comment: Либо просто нажать Rebuild (пересборка). Либо закрыть студию - удалить папки bin и obj в проекте - запустить студию - собрать проект. Оба варианта быстрее, чем тыкать конфигурации. Ещё вариант, открыть Batch build, поставить галочки напротив всех конфигураций, нажать Clean, затем Build.

Comment: Мне из этого ничего не помогло, однако. Так как пробовал. Но может кому-то и Ваш метод поможет